# MySQLi Prepared Statement reads wrong table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was recently working on a small project and one of my PHP functions checks to see if the username exists and it works, but it reads the wrong table. I want it to read todo_users and it reads the users table. Here is my code:

Connect.php

```
class Connect
{
    public $sqlHost='MySQLHost';
    public $sqlUser='MySQLUser';
    public $sqlPass='MySQLPass';
    public $sqlDB='MySQLDB';
    public $tablePrefix='todo';

    public function connect(){
        return new mysqli($this->sqlHost, $this->sqlUser, $this->sqlPass, $this->sqlDB);
    }
}
```

Note: I have replaced the sql variables for obvious security reasons.

The function:

```
public static function exists($username) {
    $connect = new Connect();
    $c = $connect->connect();
    $t = $connect->tablePrefix."_users";
    $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT username FROM `".$t."` WHERE username = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $num_row = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($result);
    if($num_row === 0) {
        return "false";
    } else {
        return "true";
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $c->close();
}
```

checkuser.php where the function is called:

```
 require_once("userfunc.php");
 if(isset($_POST["user"]))
 {
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    if(USERFUNC::exists($username)) {
        echo "YES";
    } else {
        echo "NO";
    }
 }
```

EDIT: The versions I'm using are:
PHP version 5.3.18
MySQL version   5.1.68

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you echo'ed `$t` after declaring it (`$t = $connect->tablePrefix."_users";`) to see if it is correct?

Comment: I have echoed $t and it returns todo_users and I think it's reading from the wrong table because when it checks to see if the username exists it returns true for every name that is in the users table. Plus, todo_users is empty so it shouldn't say any exists.

Comment: @user2336873 - thanks for adding the code. ceejayoz's answer is correct - you're passing a string out of the function, and that is evaluating to "true" in your check. Change `"true"` and `"false"` to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 2):

The **string** "false", like any non-empty string, will evaluate as `true` in any conditionals you have.

Do `return false;` instead of `return "false";` and I'll bet it works fine.

Comment: The return statement isn't the problem. The problem is the code is querying the wrong table. It's querying users instead of todo_users.

Comment: How do you know that? You say the evidence of that is that it's returning "true" for every name that's in the users table. Doing `return "false";` will result in that, because you're always returning `true`.

Comment: @user2336873 - there is no way it can be querying `users`. You're concatenating a prefix onto `_users`, which means that even if the prefix is empty, you'll still be looking in table `_users` (with an underscore in front) and not `users`.

Comment: All the signs point to the fact that it's querying users. During the registration process it returns "That username is not available." for every username that's in the users table. todo_users is empty so there is no reason for it to return that at all. I've also tried usernames that aren't in users and it works.

Comment: @user2336873 - echo out the SQL you're using in your query. What does that look like? Also, could you add to the question the lines of code where you call this function and check the result?

Comment: I added the code where I call the function and as for echoing the query I don't think it's possible with MySQLi prepared statements, but I get this when I use print_r on $stmt after bind_param is executed.
mysqli_stmt Object ( [affected_rows] => 0 [insert_id] => 0 [num_rows] => 0 [param_count] => 1 [field_count] => 1 [errno] => 2013 [error] => Lost connection to MySQL server during query [sqlstate] => HY000 [id] => 1 ) true

Comment: @user2336873 - all you need to is `$sql = "SELECT username FROM `".$t."` WHERE username = ?";` - you can then echo SQL as well as pass it into `prepare`.

Comment: I did that and it returned "SELECT username FROM `todo_users` WHERE username = ?". This issue shouldn't even be happening according to this information.

Comment: Just thought I'd post an update into this. I made a test script to see where the data would go if I added a user and it went into todo_users, but the id that is set to auto increment continued where the id for the table users left off.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with code you pasted.

I think you are running wrong code (old version? wrong url?) and thats why you see result from table without prefix.

Comment: If you mean the PHP/MySQL versions they are: PHP version 5.3.18
MySQL version 5.1.68

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing your `if(num_rows)` check -

```
if($num_row === 1) {  // or $num_row == 1
        return "true";
    } else {
        return "false";
    }
```

This way it will only return true if there is exactly 1 row with `username = $username` and everything else will return false.

Comment: Thanks for that information, but it didn't really answer the question.

Comment: There is now way that it is querying `users` if `$t` is returning `todo_users`. As @andrewsi stated, at most it would be table `_users` and not `users`. Either you have not 'refreshed' your code, or there is an issue somewhere else, which is why I provided a possible issue with your `num_rows`

Comment: I changed the num_rows to your suggestion and still the same result